# Setting Style attributes of ionic2 component dynamically

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
<ion-header [style.background-color]="(style|async)?.logoBackground">
    <ion-navbar >
        <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle [style.background-color]="(style|async)?.menuButtonBackground">
            <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <ion-title [style.background-color]="(style|async)?.logoBackground">
            <dynamic-logo [style]="style"></dynamic-logo>
        </ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

I have to reuse this code, over and over again.
"style"  is a variable to an JSON object, I fetch dynamically which has the "style sheet for the app".

I'd lige to write it as simple as this, on other pages:

`<dynamic-header [style]="style"></dynamic-header>`
And having a component to set these (component appended below).

Though this is not possible in ionic2, because it'll wrap the `<ion-header>` in the `<dynamic-header>` and therefor not render the page correctly.

So I'm wondering if there is an alternative to making this as a component, maybe a way of making it as a Directive, I just havn't been able to find the necessary information about @Directive..

Also tried @Directive with binding `<ion-content dynamic-content [style]="style">...</>`
AND
`[style]="(style|async)"` gives `WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value [object Object] (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).`

**TS:**

```
import { Attribute, ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, ElementRef, Input, Renderer, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { PageStyle } from "../../providers/company-service";

@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-header',
  templateUrl: 'dynamic-header.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class DynamicHeaderComponent {
  @Input() style: PageStyle;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ion-header [style.background-color]="(style|async)?.logoBackground">
    <ion-navbar >
        <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle [style.background-color]="(style|async)?.menuButtonBackground">
            <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <ion-title [style.background-color]="(style|async)?.logoBackground">
            <dynamic-logo [style]="style"></dynamic-logo>
        </ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

**reformed to directive**

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, Attribute, ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, ElementRef, Input, Renderer, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { PageStyle } from "../../providers/company-service";

@Directive({
  selector: 'dynamic-content',
  /*  templateUrl: 'dynamic-content.html',
      changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
      encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  */
})
export class DynamicContentComponent {
  @Input() style: PageStyle;

  @HostBinding('style.background-image')
  get getBackgroundImage() {
    if (this.style) {
      return this.style.backgroundImage;
    }
  }

  @HostBinding('style.background-repeat')
  get getBackgroundRepeat() {
    if (this.style) {
      return "no-repeat";
    }
  }

  @HostBinding('style.background-size')
  get getBackgroundSize() {
    if (this.style) {
      return "cover";
    }
  }

  @HostBinding('style.color')
  get getTextColor() {
    if (this.style) {
      return this.style.textColor;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From directives you can only bind single styles

```
export class DynamicHeaderComponent {
  @Input() style: PageStyle;

  // repeat this getter for every style property
  @HostBinding('style.background-color')
  get backgroundColor() {
    if(this.style) {
      return this.style.backgroundColor;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And to use it `<ion-navbar dynamic-header [style]="style">...</..>` ?

Comment: That was the idea.

Comment: Does not seem to work...
Updated Q with the directive

Comment: styles are not being changed.. propperties not set :)

Comment: Sorry, can't tell from here, why.

Comment: Seems it doesn't update when style attribute updates?